# Dificuldade em fazer um filtro em uma query sql (postgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, filtro

Olá!

Tenho uma tabela de pagamento com os seguinte campos.

data, loja, caixa, cupom, pagamento, valor.

Em alguns cupons podem haver várias formas de pagamento, pois o cliente pode pagar em dinheiro e cartão por exemplo.

Então em um exemplo prático, pode ocorrer a seguinte situação:

| data | loja | caixa | cupom | pagamento | valor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02-03-2022 | 1 | 3 | 4358 | dinheiro | 83.00 |
| 02-03-2022 | 1 | 3 | 4358 | cartao debito | 14.80 |
| 02-03-2022 | 1 | 3 | 4358 | crediario | 157.63 |

Reparem que o mesmo cupom aparece em 3 registros com formas de pagamento diferentes.

Meu cliente pediu um relatório, o qual traga todos os cupons que usou o pagamento 'crediario' e quais outros pagamentos usou no mesmo cupom.

Fiz uma query usando "having count(cupom)>1" para me trazer todos os cupons com mais de um pagamento, entretanto, se eu colocar no filtro "pagamento='crediario'", ele me trás somente as linhas com o pagamento crediario. E é justamente esse o problema, pois tenho que colocar "crediario" no filtro, mas precisa trazer as outras formas de pagamento que usou no mesmo cupom.

Segue abaixo a query que fiz.

```
select
  data,
  loja,
  caixa,
  cupom,
  pagamento,
  sum(valor) as total
from tab_pagamentos
where data='2022-03-02'
and loja=1
and pagamento = 'crediario'
group by data,loja,caixa,cupom,pagamento
having count(cupom)>1
order by caixa,cupom;
```

O meu banco é postgreSQL.

Comment: Também tentei usar o **union all** mas não tive sucesso.

Comment: Tente uma subquery com EXISTS https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS

Comment: select distinct cupom? se é só o cupom que vc precisa ter...

Comment: @Motta, não sei se minha query está correta, mas ainda assim não deu certo.

Comment: @RenatoC.Francisco, na verdade eu preciso de todos os cupons que o usuário determinar no relatório.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução com EXISTS , se existir UM cupom com 'crediario' retorna todos.

Os "alias" T1 e T2 para evitar colisão de nomes pois a busca e na mesma tabela.

Talvez seja preciso ajustar a chave da tabela.

```
select data,
           loja,
           caixa, 
           cupom, 
           pagamento, 
           sum(valor) as total 
    from tab_pagamentos t1
    where data='2022-03-02' 
    and loja=1 
    and exists (select null
                from tab_pagamentos t2
                where t2.cupom = t1.cupom /*chave tabela*/
                and t2.pagamento = 'crediario'
                and t2.data='2022-03-02' 
    and loja=1 
    group by data,
             loja,
             caixa,
             cupom
    order by caixa,cupom;
```

[Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS)

Comment: Copie rápido pois se negativarem irei remover. E vão ... rsrs

Comment: não entendi o ajuste na chave da tabela.

Comment: A chave da tabela (PK) que garanta que os dados são os mesmos pesquisados "podem haver várias formas de pagamento" eu suponho seja "cupom".

Comment: O campo "cupom" é uma chave primária.

Answer (score 0):

Com a sugestão do @Motta de usar o "EXISTS" e usando uma terceira tabela, a qual, gravo o resumo do cupom fiscal, consegui fazer da forma que eu precisava.

Essa tabela que gravo o resumo do cupom tem quase os mesmos campos que a tabela de pagamentos. A diferença são as informações das finalizadoras que existem na tabela de pagamento e na tabela de resumo do cupom não tem.

Segue minha query como exemplo para eventuais dúvidas de outros usuários.

```
select 
  cast(c.dta_movto as date) "DATA",
  c.loja LOJA,
  c.caixa PDV,
  c.cupom CUPOM,
  p.pagamento COD_FINALIZADORA,
  f.descricao "DESCRICAO",
  sum(p.valor) VALOR
from resumo_cupom c 
left join tab_pagamentos p on
  c.dta_movto = p.dta_movto and
  c.loja = p.loja and
  c.caixa = p.caixa and
  c.cupom = p.cupom
inner join tab_finalizadora f on 
  p.loja = f.cod_loja and 
  p.pagamento = f.cod_finalizadora
where exists 
  (select pp.pagamento
      from tab_pagamentos pp 
      where pp.cupom = c.cupom
      and pp.dta_movto = c.dta_movto 
      and pp.loja = c.loja 
      and pp.caixa = c.caixa
      and pp.pagamento = 'crediario')
and c.dta_movto = '2022-03-02' 
and c.loja = 1 
and c.caixa = 6
group by c.dta_movto,c.loja,c.caixa,c.cupom,p.pagamento,f.descricao;
```